# Borrow during subtracting operation (sbc asm instruction) on 6502?

Tags: 6502

When the borrow (i.e. carry flag is cleared) happens during subtracting operation (sbc asm instruction) on 6502 used by NES? Is it each time the result is negative (-1 to -128)?

Many thanks!
Thanks
STeN

Comment: Carry is for unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

On a 6502 `SBC n` is exactly identical to `ADC (n EOR $FF)` — it's one's complement. So carry is clear when `A + (operand ^ 0xff) + existing carry` is less than 256.

EDIT: so, if carry is set then the subtraction occurs without borrow. If carry is clear then subtraction occurs with borrow. Therefore if carry is set after the subtraction then there was no borrow. If carry is clear then there was borrow.

If you want to test whether a result is negative, check the sign bit implicitly via a `BMI` or `BPL`.

It's a bit more complicated than that if in decimal mode on a generic 6502 but the NES variant doesn't have decimal mode so ignore anything you read about that.

---

To clarify re: the comments below; if you're treating numbers as signed then `127` is `+127`, `128` is `-128`, etc. Normal two's complement. Nothing special. E.g.

```
LDA #-63    ; i.e. 1100 0001
SEC
SBC #65     ; i.e. 0100 0001
; result in accumulator is now -128, i.e. 1000 0000,
; and carry remains set because there was no borrow

BPL somewhere     ; wouldn't jump, because -128 is negative
BMI somewhereElse ; would jump, because -128 is negative
```

The following is exactly equivalent in terms of inner workings:

```
LDA #-63    ; i.e. 1100 0001
SEC         ; ... everything the same up until here ...
ADC #65     ; i.e. 1011 1110 (the complement of 0100 0001)

; result = 1100 0001 + 1011 1110 + 1 = [1] 0111 1111 + 1 = [1] 1000 0000
;                                       ^
;                                       |
;                                     carry
; = -128
```

So, as above, defining "the result" as per the 6502 manual and ordinary programmatic meaning of "the thing sitting in the accumulator", you can test whether the result is positive or negative as stated above, e.g.

```
SBC $23
BMI resultWasNegative
resultWasPositive: ...
```

If you're interested in whether the complete result *would have been* negative (i.e. had it fitted into the accumulator) then you can also check the overflow flag. If overflow is set then that means that whatever is in the accumulator has the wrong sign because of the 8-bit limit. So you can do the equivalent of an exclusive OR between overflow and sign:

```
SBC $23

BVC signIsTheOpposite
BMI resultWasNegative
JMP resultWasPositive

signIsTheOpposite:
BPL resultWasNegative
JMP resultWasPositive
```

Comment: > If you want to test whether a result is negative, check the sign bit implicitly via a BMI or BPL. --- INCORRECT! For example, (-128) minus 1 is still negative but in accumulator you'll get positive byte-wide value +127. In the cases like that one should check overflow flag and if it's set, the value of sign (negative) flag is incorrect (i.e. inverted).

Comment: @lvd I don't agree with your assessment, or particularly with your temperament. It's like arguing that anybody who writes in C and says that the result of `10 / 7` is `0` is "INCORRECT!". As defined by the 6502 data sheet and manuals, and by all common sense, the result is the thing in the accumulator. Have extended answer to cover overflow on the off-chance it'll make you happy but, honestly, in amongst your schoolyard shouting, you're merely splitting hairs. A simple fact of fixed-size arithmetic is that overflow and underflow may change the sign, but the sign is changed.

Comment: (and, as per the edit history, I initially misread lvd's comment; hopefully I've corrected my error)

Comment: The question asked is clearly asked by novice. It is wise to put one's attention to the niceties like overflow in signed computations. Otherwise the same experience could be earned in the much more unhappy way by the person that tries assembler for the first time.

Comment: Check my edit history and you'll see that I managed to trip myself up on your comment despite holding myself out as somebody who can answer the question. So I think you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Tommy's answer is correct, but I have a simpler way of looking at it.

Operations in the 6502's ALU are all 8 bit so you can think of a subtraction like this (for $65 and $64):

```
 01100101
-01100100
 ========
 00000001
```

What I do is imagine the subtraction is a 9 bit (unsigned) operation with the 9th bit of the accumulator set to 1, so $65 - $64 would look like this:

```
 1 01100101
-  01100100
 ==========
 1 00000001
```

Whereas $64 - $65 would look like this

```
 1 01100100
-  01100101
 ==========
 0 11111111
```

The new carry bit is the imaginary 9th bit of the result.

Essentially, the carry is set when the operand interpreted as an unsigned number is greater than the accumulator interpreted as an unsigned number. Or to be pedantic when

```
 A < operand - 1 + oldcarry
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the result may as well be positive.

Example:

```
lda #$10
sec
sbc #$f0
```

Carry will be clear after that and Accumulator will be $20.

To test for positive/negative values after substraction use the N(egative)-flag of the status-register and the branches evaluating it (BMI/BPL).